# Use curl to login to online banking

Tags: php, forms, curl

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCfB6BP-PN4) and applying it to [my bank's homepage](https://www.pnc.com/en/personal-banking.html). The page's login form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.onlinebanking.pnc.com/alservlet/OnlineBankingServlet">
        <span id="userIdInput" name="userIdInput">
            <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" placeholder="ENTER USER ID" autocomplete="off">
        </span>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="olb-btn">
        <div class="uid-block">
            <label for="save_user_id" id="save-user-id"><input type="checkbox" value="true" id="save_user_id" name="save_user_id"><span>Save User ID</span></label>
            <a class="recover-link" href="https://www.onlinebanking.pnc.com/alservlet/ForgotUserIdServlet" target="&quot;_blank&quot;">Forgot User ID or Password?</a>

        </div>
</form>
```

I've tried `curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar --data 'userId=myBankId' --data 'olb-btn=Login' --data 'save_user_id=true' --output login-response https://www.onlinebanking.pnc.com/alservlet/OnlineBankingServlet` and also `curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar -u myBankId --output login-response2 https://www.onlinebanking.pnc.com/alservlet/OnlineBankingServlet`

Do these commands look properly formed? The resulting html output doesn't match the html I see when I manually login, which takes me to a secondary form page to prompt for my password.

Comment: The bank could have used some other security measures. Use an other example.

Comment: I can `curl -u` other sites no problem. The end goal here is to script out the download of my .qfx transactions.

Comment: Use the Network tab of your browser's debugger to what request is actually being sent. In Firefox, you can copy a request as a curl command from the context menu.